# Where can i find reading source code functions on_idle, on_initialize, and on_finalize of the pallet?

Tags: polkadot

I am learning substrate lifecycle [transaction lifecycle](https://docs.substrate.io/learn/transaction-lifecycle/#validating-and-queuing-transactions)
in the section "Executing transactions and producing blocks", I want to read the source to understand the operation of Initializing a block, Executing the transactions to be included in a block, and Finalizing block building. But I don't find out source code for that. let's help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is using cargo doc.

E.G.

Search `on_initalize`: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_service/index.html?search=on_initalize.

Click one and then click the source in the new page.

[image]

And you can see the file tree, you can follow that to navigate in GitHub repo if you prefer using GitHub.

[image]

---

And for your question I suggest you starting from `frame_executive`.

Check https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/executive.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I have a question for you. 
"After the block has been initialized, each valid transaction is executed in order of transaction priority."
I can't find the section source code for executed transactions. Where is it in the `executive module`?